# Check this problem of linear algebra why this happened

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

showing the subspaces spanned by$S=\{\alpha,\beta\} $ and $T=\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$ where $\alpha=(1,2,1),\beta=(3,1,5),\gamma=(3,-4,7)$ , I got $\gamma=-3\alpha+2\beta$ and here both $S\subseteq T$ and $T\subseteq S$ are shown . But Please someone explain why both the inclusion is shown here. I badly need it please, please

Comment: Showing what?${}$

Comment: To show T = S. And also addition of a linearly dependent vector to the spanning set of vectors does not change the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$
S = \{a_1 \alpha + a_2 \beta : a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}\\
T = \{a_1 \alpha + a_2 \beta + a_3 \gamma : a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$
Clearly, we have $S \subseteq T$, since for any $x \in S$, we have
$$
x = a_1 \alpha + a_2 \beta = a_1 \alpha + a_2 \beta + 0\gamma \in T
$$
In order to show that $T\subseteq S$, note that for any $x \in T$, we have
$$
x = a_1 \alpha + a_2 \beta + a_3 \gamma\\
= a_1 \alpha + a_2 \beta + a_3 (-3\alpha + 2\beta)\\
= (a_1 - 3a_3) \alpha + (a_2+2a_3) \beta \in S
$$

Answer (score 3):

The equality $S=T$ is false.

Apparently you wish to prove that $\left\langle S\right\rangle =\left\langle T\right\rangle$.

By definition one has
$$\left\langle S\right\rangle =\left\{\lambda _1\alpha+\lambda _2\beta\colon \lambda _1, \lambda _2\in \mathbb F\right\}$$
$$\left\langle T\right\rangle =\left\{\mu _1\alpha+\mu _2\beta +\mu _3 \gamma\colon \mu _1, \mu _2, \mu_3\in \mathbb F\right\}$$

I will prove that $\left\langle T\right\rangle \subseteq\left\langle S\right\rangle$.

Let $u\in \left\langle T\right\rangle$. There exist $\mu _2, \mu _2, \mu _3\in \mathbb F$ such that $u=\mu _1\alpha+\mu _2\beta +\mu_3 \gamma$ and since, according to you, $\gamma =-3\alpha +2\beta$, one gets $$u=\mu _1\alpha +\mu _2\beta +\mu _3(-3\alpha +2\beta)=(\mu _1-3\mu _3)\alpha +(\mu _2+2\beta \mu_3)\beta.$$

Taking $\lambda _1=\mu _1-3\mu _3$ and $\lambda _2=\mu _2+2\beta \mu_3$ proves that $u\in \langle S\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

To show T = S. And also inclusion of a linearly dependent vector to the spanning set of vectors does not change the space.